# Add exapanding animation to a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-linearlayout

Actually in my app if i click on a **button** a `LinearLayout` set `onCreate` at "`height:0`" is set to "`height:630`" but there is no any animation and it appear instantly so it's not nice to see.

How can i add any animation to it something like it's bouncing out or just coming up smootly?

Here is my `onClick` code where i set the height to the layout

```
menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = recyclerContainner.getLayoutParams();
        if(params.height == 0) {
            params.height = 630;

            recyclerContainner.setLayoutParams(params);


        }else {
            params.height = 0;
            recyclerContainner.setLayoutParams(params);

        }

    }
});
```

[image]

I've also tryed to animate it using BounceIterpolator but it's animate just the content inside the LinearLayout and not the resizing of it

Here is the code of it

[image]

```
menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = recyclerContainner.getLayoutParams();
        if(params.height == 0) {

            params.height = 630;

            recyclerContainner.setLayoutParams(params);

            BounceInterpolator bounceInterpolator = new BounceInterpolator();
            ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(recyclerContainner, "translationY", 100f, 0 );
            anim.setInterpolator(bounceInterpolator);
            anim.setDuration(1100).start();


        }else {
            params.height = 0;
            recyclerContainner.setLayoutParams(params);

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Well, seems that you have web-dev background... But believe me or not, in android, there is no automatic transitions, you've to make it yourself... You can learn about animations in android [here](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/overview)

Comment: You can use BottomSheet for this kind of animation

Comment: @SanjayKumar look's very interesting but i was looking for something a bit simplier i mean i have yet implemented in my LinearLayout a RecyclerView so i would have to change a lot of code for implement it

Comment: @DudeCoder i tryed to use the BounceInterpolator with ObjectAnimator but the issue is remaining that the animation works but the main anymation of resizing the height doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

On Create set:

```
recyclerContainer.animate().scaleY(0.0f).setDuration(0);
```

On click:

```
recyclerContainer.animate().scaleY(1.0f).setDuration(500);
```

EDIT: This requires the initial height of the `recyclerContainer` to have 630 height or whatever the "popped up" height is supposed to be, if initial height is 0 the scaling of 0 would result in 0 :)

edit:
the new onclick code:

```
menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(isUp) {
            recyclerContainer.animate().scaleY(0.0f).setDuration(500);
            isUp = false;
        }else {
            recyclerContainer.animate().scaleY(1.0f).setDuration(500);
            isUp = false;
        }

    }
});
```

where "isUp is a boolean that you initially declare as false after setting scaleY in onCreate.

Comment: The animation is cool but the issue is still that it's anymate the LinearLayout but if i click on the Button it's still will set the 630p height without any animation

Comment: you need to replace the code in your onclick with the animation, see my last edit above.

Comment: Still if i initialize recyclerContainer to 630 height when i open the activity it's yet open and that's not what i want i mean i want that it compare just if i click to the button and i click again to hide it

Comment: yes but if you set it to initial height 630, and then you run `recyclerContainer.animate().scaleY(0.0f).setDuration(0);`in your onCreate it will be scaled to 0 height before it becomes visible.